# List of TzId and TimeZoneName in iCal.Net for iCloud Caldav

Tags: caldav, ical-dotnet

1) What is the difference between TimeZoneName and TzId properties of IDateTime inside Ical.Net.Interfaces.DataTypes?
2) Where can I find complete list for both TimeZoneName and TzId ?

Answer (score 0):

> What is the difference between TimeZoneName and TzId properties of
>   IDateTime inside Ical.Net.Interfaces.DataTypes?

[`TimeZoneName` returns the value of `TzId`](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/blob/master/v2/ical.NET/DataTypes/CalDateTime.cs#L259). It's a historical artifact; I consider it deprecated. I may remove it at some point.

> Where can I find complete list for both TimeZoneName and TzId

`TzId` is a mutable property, but assigned values *should* represent [one of the time zones available in NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/1.2.x/api/NodaTime.DateTimeZoneProviders.html), which ical.net [uses under the hood](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net/blob/master/net-core/Ical.Net/Utility/DateUtil.cs#L102). These are the `tzdb` (IANA), BCL (Windows) and serialization databases.

If you want to enumerate all of the values in each time zone database, have a look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/jrolstad/5ca7d78dbfe182d7c1be) for inspiration. (Additional questions about NodaTime should be asked separately. NodaTime internals have nothing to do with ical.net.)

Comment: Ok. Just want to ask that I am getting "Asia/Calcutta" for india but list at https://gist.github.com/jrolstad/5ca7d78dbfe182d7c1be has "Asia/Kolkata". And I am getting "US/Pacific" also but its not in the list. I am getting the timezones mentioned in list but I am also getting timezones which are not in list like US states strings like US/Eastern and GTM-06 in tzId property.

Comment: Calcutta is sometimes Kolkata in the tzdb (IANA) database. US/Pacific is in the serialization database.